# gd enabled but still reports PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()

Tags: php, gd

Has anyone met this problem ?

I've checked the output of `phpinfo()`,and see `gd` is enabled.

**UPDATE**

I built PHP with `--with-gd`, but only `GIF Support` and `PNG Support` are in the output of phpinfo(), how do I enable `JPEG Support`?

Comment: How about adding the code for the call and the exact error string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it wasn't built against libjpeg. See if "JPEG Support" in the **gd** section is "enabled".

Comment: Does `gd` enable JPEG amtomatically?

Comment: Not if it doesn't have the libraries to build against.

Comment: But it shouldn't happen because I'm installed libjpeg libjpeg-devel by `yum -y install libjpeg libjpeg-devel` before configuring PHP.

Comment: Did you recompile PHP and GD after installing the jpeg-devel rpm? Simply having jpeg-devel installed won't magically enable it in GD if GD was compiled without the support.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but:

- What version of php are you using ? (did you compile it yourself?)
- Under gd, do you see anything related to jpg ?
- What is your `Configure Command`? Does it say anything about jpg ?

Comment: My `Configure Command` doesn't say anything about jpg, no gif/png, but I can see gif/png support in the output of `phpinfo()`.